# Why does Firebase Realtime Database say I have more connections than I actually do?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am utilizing Firebase's realtime database to host a chatroom type thing. Ever since I started, the analytics have only shown the maximum number of connections I have had. Here is an example of what the analytics look like:

[image]

Even when I click on the information "?" next to connections it says, "The number of simultaneous realtime connections to your database". You can even see in the graph that the number has gone down but the number on the left stays at 100/100.

Does anyone know why this is or how I can see the actual number of realtime connections?

Comment: This is the actual number of sockets that the database server had open at that moment. If that doesn't match the number of active clients you have, it'll be more likely we can answer why that is if you show a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and/or additional debugging information.

Comment: Hi Frank, I am not very versed in stack overflow so I am not sure if this is the best place to respond. This is a chrome extension that I have not published yet and I am still in the testing phase. The weird thing to me about the connections number is that it has always been the max number I have ever had. On Jan 2nd I had 21 and thats what it said as connections until Jan 10th when I exceeded that number. I cant find any other information from the firebase page that shows me realtime connections. I also never even had anywhere near 100 simultaneous connections during my testing.

Comment: The number shown in that chart is the actual number of sockets that the database server had open at that moment. If that doesn't match with what you expected, the only way we can help is if you share a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).